# New Perfect 2-bit Error Correction Code - Are there any other?

Tags: sphere-packing, gray-codes

I have recently looked through perfect error correcting codes and found the Hamming(7,3) and Golay(23,7). Using a computer program I have found a new 2 bit perfect error correcting code: Code(90, 2).
Proof: 1+90+89*90/2=2^12

This code has 5 bits and can theoretically correct any 2 bit errors in an 85 bit message - total: 90 bits.

I have ran the following computer program and I think it confirms that there are no other perfect error correcting codes that can correct up to 10'000 bits of error and have a total length less than 1'000'000.

Can some math prove/disprove the existence of such codes? Are there any other bigger than 3 bit perfect error correcting codes? Does the [monster group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_group) or any other groups relate to such codes?

```
        int maxn = 1000000;
        int maxe = 10000;
        long[] sum = new long[maxe];
        sum[0] = 1;
        HashSet<int> codes = new HashSet<int>();
        string s1 = "";
        for (int n = 1; n < maxn; n++)
        {
            long[] news = new long[maxe];
            news[0] = 1;
            for (int j = 1; j < Math.Min(n, maxe); j++)
            {
                long v = news[j] = news[j - 1] + sum[j] - (j >= 2 ? sum[j - 2] : 0);
                if ((v & (v - 1)) == 0)
                {
                    if (n > j * 2 + 1 && !codes.Contains(j))
                    {
                        codes.Add(j);
                        s1 += "Code(" + n.ToString() + "," + (2 * j + 1).ToString() + ")\r\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            if (n < maxe)
            {
                news[n] = news[n - 1] + 1;
            }
            sum = news;
        }
```

Comment: That's a necessary but not a sufficient condition for the existence of a perfect code.  By a special case of the Tietäväinen-van Lint theorem, there's no perfect code with those parameters.  The Diophantine equation $1 + n + {n \choose 2} = 2^e$ is equivalent to Ramanujan's question about $y^2 + 7 = 2^x$, settled by Nagell's theorem that $(x,y) = (15, \pm 181)$ is the last pair of integer solutions.

Comment: Checking my notes I see that this is already part of Lloyd's theorem,
preceding TvL.  http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M256.13/lloyd.pdf

Comment: Comment: In practice there will be differing network packet sizes, apis, and consistency issues which would be a problem for a single perfect algorithm. Under some contrived mathematical definition then you could of course have a perfect algorithm.

Comment: Thank you @Noam D. Elkies. I believe the document you pointed to answers the question as there are no other perfect error correcting codes. This question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered by @Noam D. Elkies in the above comments with an excellent [link](http://math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M256.13/lloyd.pdf) to an article describing the problem.